# How to make lxpanel show up on both the monitors

Tags: unity, window-manager, taskbar, lxpanel

I recently installed lxpnael for having a all open windows list. It shows up by default only on one of my monitors
can I show it also on my other monitor?

also can I also do it this way - the lxpanel on any monitor only shows the windows open on that monitor?

Answer (score 4):

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2004985

Anyhow, try this:

I created two scripts in the .screenlayout/ directory with the help of ARandR:

```
~/.screenlayout$ cat single.sh 
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --off
lxpanelctl restart

~/.screenlayout$ cat dual.sh 
#!/bin/sh
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1024x0 --rotate normal
lxpanelctl restart
```

adding the string "lxpanelctl restart" by hand (ARandR doesn't do it). Then, in the file
~/.config/openbox/lxde-ec.xml
I added the following lines between two  lines:

```
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="W-2">
  <action name="Execute">
  <command>sh ~/.screenlayout/dual.sh</command>
  </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="W-1">
  <action name="Execute">
  <command>sh ~/.screenlayout/single.sh</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

so that using <1> and <2> I can switch between single and dual monitor configuration.

Comment: This does nothing for me: lxpanel stays visible only on the first monitor.

Comment: This is almost literally an answer that is 10 years old. I would guess that the config has changed during that time so could be that the answer is outdated